# C++ Inheritance error

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Here's the code that triggers the error (Player.cpp):

```
#include "Library.h"

Player::Player(){
    //generate player stats
    str = rand()%6+1+1;
    inte = rand()%6+1;
    c = (rand()%6+1)+floor(str/3);
    wis = rand()%6+1+floor(inte/4);
    ref = rand()%6+1+floor(wis/4);
    i = floor(ref/3);
    hp = floor((str+(wis/3)+(ref/2)));
    xp = 0;
}

//printStats (constant Player player reference)
//prints player's stats
void Player::printStats() const{
    cout << "\nSTR: " << str << endl;
    cout << "INTE: " << inte << endl;
    cout << "C: " << c << endl;
    cout << "WIS: " << wis << endl;
    cout << "REF: " << ref << endl;
    cout << "I: " << i << endl;
    cout << "HP: " << hp << endl;
    cout << "XP: " << xp << endl;
    cout << "Gold: " << gold << endl;
    cout << "Level: " << lvl << endl << endl;
}

int Player::giveOptions(int amount,string op1, string op2, string op3, string op4, string op5){
    cout << "Type the number then press the enter key to choose or type 'help' for extra commands." << endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=amount;i++){
        string s;
        switch(i){
        case 1:
            s = op1;
            break;
        case 2:
            s = op2;
            break;
        case 3:
            s = op3;
            break;
        case 4:
            s = op4;
            break;
        case 5:
            s = op5;
            break;
        }
        cout << i << ". " << s << endl;
    }
    while(true){
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        if (s == "1")
            return 1;
        else if (s == "2")
            return 2;
        else if (s == "3")
            return 3;
        else if (s == "4")
            return 4;
        else if (s == "5")
            return 5;
        else{
            if (s == "stats")
                printStats();
            else if (s == "help"){
                cout << "Type the number that is next to the option you wish to choose then press the enter key, or 'stats' to print all of your stats." << endl;
                cout << "E.G:\n1. Town\nI want to go to the town\n1" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "Command not recognised. If you're confused, type 'help'." << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

*(Original question below)*

I'm fairly basic in C++, and I'm not sure why this is producing an error. In Player.cpp, all members of Entity that I thought were inherited produce the error, "x is not a member of Player". My only thought is that I'm using inheritance wrong.

Entity.h:

```
#include "Library.h"

using namespace std;
class Entity {
public:
    void printStats() const;
protected:
    //player stats
    std::string name;
    double str;     //strength
    double wis;     //wisdom
    double ref;     //reflex
    double hp;      //health points
    double i;       //initiative
    double inte;    //intelligence
    double c;       //courage
    int gold;       //gold
    int xp;         //experience
    int ap;         //armour points
    int wd;         //weapon damage
    int lvl;        //level
    int sp;         //skill points
};
```

Player.h

```
#include "Library.h"

using namespace std;

class Player: public Entity{
public:
    Player();
    int giveOptions(int amount, string op1, string op2, string op3, string op4, string op5);
};
```

Comment: `#include`d `"Entity.h"` in your Player.h ?

Comment: @Xeo: It wouldn't even compile otherwise. It's probably in `"Library.h"`.

Comment: You should add a code sample that triggers the error. This does not seem incorrect as it is. Also, don't add `using namespace` to your headers, as that will force the collapse of both namespaces for all users of your headers.

Comment: Okay, I'll delete the using namespace and post a code sample that triggers the error.

Comment: @Pig Head: You still need to post at a minimum the complete Player.h and Entity.h

Comment: @Pig Head - Place `using namespace std;` in source files (i.e., .cpp files).

Comment: Those WERE the complete Player and Entity headers.

Comment: @Pig Head - What is there in `Library.h`?

Comment: You need to sort out your includes.  You can't have both Player.h and Entity.h include Library.h, and yet have Library.h include both of those headers.  You have a mutual dependency.  It should be hierarchical.

Comment: Okay - may I ask why, and how I can get around this?

Comment: @Pig Head: Don't include "Entity.h" in "Library.h", just where you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void Player::printStats() const
```

Should be, according to your headers:

```
void Entity::printStats() const
```

On the includes, do one of these, whichever suits your code best:

1.

- `Player.h` must include `Entity.h`
- `Library.h` should *not* include `Player.h` or `Entity.h`
- `Player.h` and/or `Entity.h` can include `Library.h` if really needed.

or 2.

- `Player.h` must include `Entity.h`, but *not* `Library.h`
- `Entity.h` must *not* include `Library.h`
- `Library.h` can include `Player.h` and/or `Entity.h`

This avoids the cyclic dependencies you currently have - which leads to `Player` being defined before `Entity` and giving the `base class undefined` error.

Comment: It is included. I'll provide a code sample of the Player.cpp.

Comment: @Pig Head: It's not included in your posted `Player.h` - but yes, show us complete code

Comment: Now that you mention it, the first one is different: `player.h(3): error C2504: 'Entity' : base class undefined`

Comment: Thanks for those options - I was thinking they would be fairly impractical after looking at my code, then realised I was looking at the cpp files. Thanks very much for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler compliains - neither the class `Entity` nor the `Player` has a member variable called `x`. You need to include `"Entity.h"` in the `Player` header file, since in the current translation unit compiler doesn't know what `Player` is.

Comment: 'x' meaning the variable name.